# Is there a Flutter package that supports Server-Side Server Sent Events (SSE)?

Tags: flutter, dart, server-sent-events

package for Flutter to use Server-Side Server Sent Events

i already tried [text](https://pub.dev/packages/sse)  package but there is no documentation for the Server-Side

is there any package to use Flutter as Server-Side SSE ?

or is there any recommendation to send from Flutter desktop to PC Directly ?

Comment: What specifically you're planning on to on the server-side?

Comment: I want to send list data from Flutter to Web Browser in Local PC